# Does a pool of connections really improve the overall perfomance?

Tags: vb.net, connection-pooling

I have this code in Visual Basic, every time I have a new insert:

```
Private _conn As SqlConnection 

Public Function Include(ByVal pSql As String, Optional timeout As Integer = 120) As Boolean
   Try
        Dim SQL_Str = "my string of conection... with database. not put on this example"
        _conn = New SqlConnection(SQL_Str)
        _conn.Open()

        _adapter = New SqlDataAdapter

        cmd.CommandTimeout = timeout
        cmd.Connection = _conn
        cmd.CommandText = pSql
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text

        _adapter.InsertCommand = cmd

        _adapter.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

    Catch ex As Exception
        InputBox("New Error on Sql cmd: ", , pSql)
    End Try

     _conn.Close()
     _conn.Dispose()
     _conn = Nothing

    _adapter.Dispose()
    _adapter = Nothing
End Function
```

Ok this is a straightforward way to update the database.

But supose I have 1000 connections at the same time, do the application would support this kind of approach?

Do this method support simultaneous threads acessing the _conn object?

Is it really necessary to create a pool of connections to handle data?

Do a pool of connections will really improve something?

E.g. with this I'm overloading the application instead of the database?

If so, how would I do it on VbNet/Visual Basic?

Comment: `SqlConnection` already performs spooling behind the scenes by default. So you should not worry about that; what you should worry about is the fact that `_conn` is class-level but you create and destroy it within a method call as if it was local, and that you are not using [`Using`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/using-statement).

Comment: So shouldn't I create and dispose it? If I do it I'm getting a new connection every time and not using the connection pool?

Comment: @felipe you *are* using the connection pool, unless you've disabled it. With pooling enabled, close() just make the connection available to be reused. it doesn't actually close it.

Comment: Open the connect and close it as fast as possible. Pooling is already taken care of. If you have 1000 thread active at the same time, then I think you have a problem. It's recommended to not have more thread than processor\core.

Comment: @felipe 1000 connecitons is fine if you have max_pool_size set to allow that many. Otherewise the other connections get to wait for a free connection or timeout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Yes*, pooled connections really are faster. They keep you from needing to continually re-negotiate login and protocol information. Even better, this is already built into the `SqlConnection` type, and it's done in a reasonably thread-safe way (where the existing code is *not*).

The short version is you really do want to create a brand new connection object for most queries, and you do **not** want to try to share the same connection variable throughout an application or session.

Given that, I see several big problems in that code:

1. Treating a class-level `_conn` variable as if it were local, making it impossible to share instances of this class safely across threads.
2. No mechanism to clean up the connection if an exception is thrown (needs a `Finally` or `Using` block. Just closing after the `Catch` isn't good enough.
3. No way to pass separate query parameters in the function signature. This will force you to write horribly insecure code elsewhere that's crazy-vulnerable to sql injection attacks. It's the kind of thing where you wake up one morning to find out you were hacked over a year ago, and IMO borders on professional malpractice.
4. Mixing UI code with utility code.

You want something more like this:

```
Private cnString As String = "my string of conection... with database. not put on this example"

Public Sub Include(pSql As String, parameters() As SqlParamter, Optional timeout As Integer = 120)
   Using conn As New SqlConnectioN(cnString), _
         cmd As New SqlCommand(pSql, conn)

        If parameters IsNot Nothing AndAlso parameters.Length > 0 Then
            cmd.Parameters.AddRange(parameters)
        End If

        conn.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
End Sub
```

And you might call it like this (assuming type or instance name is `DB`):

```
Dim pSql As String = "INSERT INTO [ExampleTable] (FirstName, LastName, CreationDate) VALUES (@FirstName, @LastName, @CreationDate)"
Dim parameters = {
    New SqlParameter("@FirstName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20),
    New SqlParameter("@LastName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20),
    New SqlParameter("@CreationDate", SqlDbType.DateTime)
}
parameters(0).Value = "John"
parameters(1).Value = "Smith"
parameters(2).Value = DateTime.Now

Try
    DB.Include(pSql, parameters)
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(String.Format("New Error on Sql cmd:{0}{1}{0}{0}Message:{2}",vbCrLf, pSql, ex.Message)
End Try
```